# Easiest way to insert a row with a unknown foreign key but known information about other columns

Tags: mysql, insert

So to clear up the question a bit, I have a table we'll call it "tAuthor" and another table called "tBook". The tables have the following columns.

**tAuthor**

- id - INT (PK)
- fname - VARCHAR(50)
- lname - VARCHAR(50)

**tBook**

- id - INT (PK)
- authorid - INT (PK)
- name - VARCHAR(50)

If I had the authors firstname and lastname and wanted to insert a new book into tBook for them, is there an easy way to have the insert statement auto fill in the authorid WHERE fname = "Known" and lname = "Known"?

I figured I could always have two statements, a select statement that returns the id WHERE fname="Known" and lname="Known" and then run the insert statement with the id returned. I was just curious if there was another way?

Comment: But what about the book name column that is not known?

Comment: How is this also a PHP related question? You can use Java.

Comment: @Spidy: then you must define the language if any. the primary guess is PHP

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Its a mysql question, that's it. Language does not need to be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tBook (name, authorid)
VALUES(SELECT 'NewBook', id
       FROM tAuthor
       WHERE tAuthor.fname = 'FirstName'
       and tAuthor.lname = 'LastName')
```

I wouldn't recommend using an Authors name for this as there could be duplicates.  However this statement will do the insert you require.  You basically do a sub-select from the table you need your ID from and fill in the rest of the information as hardcoded values rather than values to retrieve.  This is also a great way to do multiple updates if you need to update a bigger set of records that all share a common element.